# proving $\big \lfloor xn-\frac 1n \big\rfloor\neq \big\lfloor xn+\frac 1n\big\rfloor$

Tags: real-numbers, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, diophantine-approximation

How can I prove that for any real number $x$ there are infinitely many integers $n$ such:$$\Big \lfloor xn-\frac 1n \Big\rfloor\neq \Big\lfloor xn+\frac 1n\Big\rfloor$$

Comment: You could start by showing it is true for integers and rationals, and then consider irrationals

Comment: Is this known?  I worked out the sequence for $x=\pi$ and found [A265739](https://oeis.org/A265739)...and on that page it says that the sequence is merely "conjectured to be infinite."  Similarly [A265742](https://oeis.org/A265742) for $x=e$.

Comment: For $x=\sqrt 2$, on the other hand ,we appear to get [A002965](https://oeis.org/A002965) which is infinite.  (Note:  one would still have to prove that these sequences match, I only checked the first dozen terms or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediately obvious for rational $x$, since there are infinite natural numbers $n$ such that $xn$ is an integer, and therefore $\lfloor xn-\epsilon\rfloor\neq\lfloor xn+\epsilon\rfloor$ for any strictly positive $\epsilon$.

For irrational $x$, we need some extra tools.  Specifically, [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) which says that for any irrational number $x$ there are infinitely many "good" rational approximations $\frac pq$ that satisfy $$\left|x-\frac pq\right|<\frac1{q^2}$$I believe these are precisely the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) estimates for $x$, but this was a long time ago for me.

Anyways, any of those estimates are such that $|xq-\lfloor xq\rfloor|<\frac1q$, so that fits your needs.